# Are the high and low fuel pressure sensors the same part?

Tags: fuel-system, sensor, pressure

I have a 2013 Ford Escape 1.6L se 2wd, my question is the high fuel pressure sensor and the low fuel pressure sensor the same part? My mechanic gave me a part # bm5z9f972a and the part # for the high pressure sensor in the car is Bm5g9f972ba. When I go to autozone and tell them the part only one fuel pressure sensor shows, so Are both high and low fuel pressure sensors the same part?

Comment: Spoke to ford themselves and both low and high fuel pressure sensors are the same part.

Answer (score 1):

They can be, if the working range covers the pressures required for the high and low.

The ecu will decide if the reading is within range.